# Load documents and filter them in memory javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Suppose we have a search bar and we need to do some search in the documents stored in a mongo database. Is it okay to load all documents (around 100 documents) store them into an javascript array and filter them using js methods like filter whenever the user type something in the search bar? Besides that the collection won't grow much more (max 200 documents).

Comment: Not really sure what is the exact scenario, how big the document would be ? what filter do you want, pure text compare or more advance skill like text similarity search? 
Besides, in my opinion if loading all documents to js is ok for you, including the correctness and performance. Then it's ok to do that. 
On the other hand, if you are not satisfied with performance, maybe you could further explain your question.

Comment: @鄭元傑 the document has 12 fields, the filter is just a verification to check if the typed string is a substring of a specific field nothing fancy, until now there's nothing wrong with the perfomance i was wondering if it is a bad practice to do that

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to do that.
Full index search.
with that you can search any words or sentences in your document.
And if you have a large doc or wanna to search more accurately you can use Elastic search.

[read more on mongo fullIndexSearch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/)

[Elastic search](https://www.elastic.co)

Comment: alright but what if I just want to filter by one field and also want to keep it as simple as possible, the document isn't large it has 12 fields, is it still a bad practice?